# $E \subset \mathbb R$ is an Interval $\iff E$ Is connected

Tags: real-analysis

My text gives the definition that $E$ is disconnected if there exist disjoint open sets $A, B$ such that:

1. $A \cap E$, $B \cap E$ are nonempty.
2. $(A \cap E) \cup (B \cap E) = E$.

Then for the $(\implies)$ direction, the text offers the following as proof:

Suppose $E$ is an interval and $E$ is not connected.  Then there exist disjoint open sets $A$, and $B$ with $A \cap E \ne \emptyset$, $B \cap E \ne \emptyset$, and $E \subset A \cup B$.  Suppose $a \in A \cap E$ and $b \in B \cap E$.  Inasmuch as $E$, an open set in $\mathbb R$ is a finite or countable union of open and disjoint intervals, there exist disjoint open intervals $I$ and $J$ such that $a \in I$ and $b \in J$.  Suppose $a < b$ and $J = (t, s)$.  Since $a < t < b$, $t \in E$.  However, $t \notin A \cup B$, creating a contradiction.

Is the part with $E$ being a finite or countable union of open and disjoint intervals necessary?  I did it in a much simpler way:  Without loss of generality, call the open set on the left $A$, with $a \in A \cap E$, and call the open set on the right $B$, with $b \in B \cap E$.  Now, set $c =$ sup$A$;  $a < c < b \rightarrow c \in E$.  Since $c$ is a boundary point of $A$ and $A^c$, $c \notin A$.  But $c \notin B$ either.  Otherwise, there is a $\delta$ such that $N(c, \delta) \subset B$, entailing that $A \cap B$ is nonempty, which is not possible.  As a result, we have $c \in E$ and $c \notin E$, a contradiction.

Why did the book need to use the fact that $E$ is a union of open, disjoint intervals?

Comment: There is no such thing as "left" and "right". The 2 sets can mixed up in anyway. Of course, your "proof" can still work too and won't require that theorem, but it needs to be fixed.

Comment: It seems to me that the text’s proof is not completely right. Disconnectedness of $E$ means that there are disjoint *open subsets of* $E$ with the specified property. So there would be open subsets $A$ and $B$ of $\mathbb R$ with $A\cap B\cap E=\emptyset$, not merely $A\cap B=\emptyset$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your proposed proof isn't quite right. The problem is that it's not guaranteed that there is a "left" or "right" open set - this would be true if $A$ and $B$ were intervals, but they need not be. The open sets $A$ and $B$ could interlace.

So it's not actually guaranteed that $\sup A \in E$ or that $\sup B \in E$, precisely because of this issue: If we take smaller and smaller intervals in $A$ growing to the right, and likewise for $B$, then it's certainly possible to have

$$\sup A = \sup B = \sup E \notin E$$

Notice that this is fixed precisely by knowing that an open set can be decomposed into intervals; this actually does allow you to select a "left" interval and a "right" interval, and then study how they don't intersect.

Comment: So the author avoided my error by using the Hausdorff property.  On second look, with the correction, my proof is the same as the one in the text.  TY ....

Answer (score 1):

The book needs the [Hausdorff](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hausdorff_space) separation property -- that around each of two points there are disjoint open sets.  This property is normally covered in Topology, but your book is importing the idea via $E$ being a finite or countable union of open and disjoint intervals so it can pick out two disjoint intervals as needed.