# Prove that $K \subseteq \Bbb R$ is connected if for every $a,b \in K$ with $a<b$, we have $[a,b] \subset K$

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, proof-verification, connectedness

> If $K \subseteq \mathbb R$ is such that for every $a,b \in K$ with $a<b$, we have $[a,b] \subset K$, prove that $K$ is connected.

If $a,b \in K$  with $a<b$ such that $[a,b] \subset K$, then, for every $z \in \mathbb R$ with $a<z<b$, we know that $z \in [a,b] \subset K$, i.e. $z \in K$. This proves that $K$ is an interval.

We know that, in general, a subset $S \subseteq \mathbb R$ is connected if and only if $S$ is an interval.
Therefore $K$ must be connected, since $K\subseteq R$ and $K$ is an interval.

Is this correct, or am I approaching this problem incorrectly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, if you know that an interval in $\Bbb R$ [is](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/934421) connected, then your proof is fine. (As a side note, you've proven that a *convex* subset of $\Bbb R$ [is](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/956388) [connected](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1629918).)

Comment: That's an awesome side-note! :D. Not out of redundancy, but pure curiosity, how will I go about proving the theorem had I not known an interval in $\mathbb R$ is connected? I'm assuming a proof by contradiction might be easiest? :)

Comment: @DJS : we can read about connected of intervals [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/934421), [there](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1575208), [there](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/113007), or [there](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/864796/).

Comment: This can be generalized to [linear continuum](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_continuum) and order topology (see [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/424630)).